# Grant All Defined Permisions for Database to User

Tags: sql-server

This is the verbatim question:
Grant all defined permissions for database cis605 to cis605_usr

I read the the "GRANT ALL" syntax is deprecated and only grants ANSI-92 permissions applicable to the object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

If I run this query I can see the permissions already assigned to the user but I need to see the database permissions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc, 
                pr.authentication_type_desc, pe.state_desc, 
                pe.permission_name 
FROM sys.database_principals pr
JOIN sys.database_permissions pe 
  ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
WHERE pr.name = 'cis605_usr';
```

This query returns permissions but I don't see permission_name (s) like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ect... or the database name/id:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_permission;
```

How do I find all of the database permissions and grant all of the database permissions to the user?

Comment: The `permission_name` column will show the granted permission value. If you don't see values like 'INSERT', that means the user has not been granted the permission (assuming you have permssions to view other user's permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc. are object-level permissions, not database permissions.  You can assign a user to a database role (i.e. db_owner, db_datawrite, etc) to grant these permissions at a higher level.  If you want them to be able to do everything in a database, assign them db_owner permissions.

Comment: That makes sense on why I was not seeing those permissions in the database_permission system table. I used this query to add the db_owner role to cis605_usr:
    ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER cis605_usr;
I beleive this is what he is looking for, thank you.